# TensorFlow select Labels from mnist dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist for training a nn with 5 hidden layers.

This is the way I train the neural network:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
init.run()
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for iteration in range(len(mnist.test.labels)//batch_size):
        X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
    acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
    acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
    print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)
```

I want to train the neural network to recognize only numbers from 0 to 4. I change the logits layer to have 5 outputs.

How do I filter the mnist dataset provided with TensorFlow in order to only get numbers between 0 and 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. One of them is when you extract you `X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)`. At this step your `y_batch` would have information about the value of the digit (either digit value or a one-hot of the digit).

You iterate over examples in the batch and check whether the digit is the one you care about. If yes, you add it to your `cleaned_up_batch`. Not very efficient but it will work.

---

Answer to a comment:

It is not efficient because you might need to filter the same data many times. I do not think that it would be a problem because MNIST is super small. The normal way to do it is to filter it only once, create a new dataset and write your own functions to grab next batch from it (it is actually very easy because you just randomly select k elements from the dataset)

Comment: Thank you, it's a way to go but you are right, is not that efficient, do you know any other way? I was thinking that I might be able to pass some parameters to next_batch but couldn't find that